# sklearn cross_val_score() returning same MSE for different degree polynomials

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn

The title is clear, below a code to fully reproduce my example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score, train_test_split

np.random.seed(1)

url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/selva86/datasets/master/Auto.csv'
data = pd.read_csv(url, na_values='?').dropna()

X,y = data['horsepower'], data.mpg

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.5)

lm = LinearRegression()

for i in range(1,6):
    poly = PolynomialFeatures(degree=i)
    X_train_poly = poly.fit_transform(X_train.values.reshape(-1,1))
    model = lm.fit(X_train_poly, y_train)
    scores_poly = cross_val_score(model, X_test.values.reshape(-1,1),y_test,scoring='neg_mean_squared_error',
                            cv = len(X_test), n_jobs = -1)
    
    print(f'Degree-{i} polynomial, MSE: {abs(scores_poly).mean()}')
```

Output:

```
Degree-1 polynomial, MSE: 25.214173196098535
Degree-2 polynomial, MSE: 25.214173196098535
Degree-3 polynomial, MSE: 25.214173196098535
Degree-4 polynomial, MSE: 25.214173196098535
Degree-5 polynomial, MSE: 25.214173196098535
```

I would expect to get different `MSE` for different degree polynomial..

----------EDIT-----------

I included the following line to the above `for` loop:

```
X_test_poly = poly.fit_transform(X_test)
```

And changed the `scores_poly` to use `X_test_poly` instead of `X_test`. Now I get different values for the `MSE`.

(Below the reformulated fully reproducible code)

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score, train_test_split

np.random.seed(1)

url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/selva86/datasets/master/Auto.csv'
data = pd.read_csv(url, na_values='?').dropna()

X,y = data['horsepower'].values.reshape(-1,1), data.mpg.values.reshape(-1,1)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.5)

lm = LinearRegression()

for i in range(1,6):
    poly = PolynomialFeatures(degree=i)
    X_train_poly = poly.fit_transform(X_train)
    X_test_poly = poly.fit_transform(X_test)
    model = lm.fit(X_train_poly, y_train)
    scores_poly = cross_val_score(model, X_test_poly,y_test,scoring='neg_mean_squared_error',
                            cv = len(X_test), n_jobs = -1)
    
    print(f'Degree-{i} polynomial, MSE: {abs(scores_poly).mean()}')
```

Output:

```
Degree-1 polynomial, MSE: 25.214173196098535
Degree-2 polynomial, MSE: 18.678068281482577
Degree-3 polynomial, MSE: 18.85993623145088
Degree-4 polynomial, MSE: 19.085567664927655
Degree-5 polynomial, MSE: 18.79973878463155
```

**I guess this is the correct approach, but I wonder why.. could anyone clarify?**

Comment: Looking at your code, I don't think `cross_val_score` does what you think it does.  Have a look at the workflow presented in the [User Guide](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html),

Comment: Hey, thanks for the comment. Why do you say that? If I chose `scoring = 'neg_mean_square_error'` then the result of `scores.mean()` would be the MSE of my fitted model.. no? I'm wondering, though, why do I have to use `X_test_poly` instead of only using the original `X_test` to get different results for MSE... Furthermore, in this case I use `cv = len(X_test)` since I'm studying first the Leave-One-Out approach.

Comment: I did, however, read the User Guide that you shared. But I didn't see anywhere that I was 'misunderstanding' the functionality of `cross_val_score`... I'm just starting though so that is very possible..

Comment: I don't see anywhere in the User Guide with a sequence of `model = estimator.fit(...) ... cross_val_score(model, ...`.  It's always, `... cross_val_score(estimator, ...`.

Comment: Okay.. It's still unclear to me. If I use either `estimator` or `model` (which is `estimator.fit(X_train, y_train)` in `cross_val_score`, I get the same results... I wonder, if I never run the line `model = estimator.fit(X_train, y_train)`, and I just use `cross_val_score(estimator, X_test_poly...` then I'm not really *training* my data with `X_train` and then testing with `X_test`, since I never had the line `model = estimator.fit(X_train, y_train)` run;

Comment: ... and that's why I don't think it's doing what you think it's doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With every cross validation, the model you provided will be fitted with the training data. In your first code, even though you fitted the model with a polynomial `model = lm.fit(X_train_poly, y_train)` , with every iteration inside `cross_val_score` you will refit a linear model with `X_test`. Because `X_test` is only of degree one, with every iteration, you are only scoring the linear model with degree one.

You can actually see what the `PolynomialFeatures` does (see also the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.PolynomialFeatures.html)) :

```
X,y = data[['horsepower']], data['mpg']
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.5)

poly = PolynomialFeatures(degree=3)
poly.fit_transform(X_train)[:10]
 
array([[1.000000e+00, 1.700000e+02, 2.890000e+04, 4.913000e+06],
       [1.000000e+00, 5.400000e+01, 2.916000e+03, 1.574640e+05],
       [1.000000e+00, 6.500000e+01, 4.225000e+03, 2.746250e+05],
       [1.000000e+00, 1.100000e+02, 1.210000e+04, 1.331000e+06],
       [1.000000e+00, 8.800000e+01, 7.744000e+03, 6.814720e+05],
       [1.000000e+00, 1.500000e+02, 2.250000e+04, 3.375000e+06],
       [1.000000e+00, 1.980000e+02, 3.920400e+04, 7.762392e+06],
       [1.000000e+00, 8.800000e+01, 7.744000e+03, 6.814720e+05],
       [1.000000e+00, 1.400000e+02, 1.960000e+04, 2.744000e+06],
       [1.000000e+00, 1.600000e+02, 2.560000e+04, 4.096000e+06]])
```

The first column is the intercept (all ones), second column your X_train or `horsepower` followed by square of `horsepower` and then cubic of `horsepower` . `LinearRegression()` fits this matrix and does not do any transformation of the input for you.

So note that you most likely what to fit the linear model with `LinearRegression(intercept = False)` since the intercept is already in the polynomial transformation.

What you consider doing is using `Pipeline` as shown in this [sklearn documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/linear_model.html#polynomial-regression-extending-linear-models-with-basis-functions) :

```
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline

for i in range(1,6):
    model = Pipeline([('poly', PolynomialFeatures(degree=i)),
    ('linear', LinearRegression(fit_intercept=False))])
    scores_poly = cross_val_score(model, X_test,y_test,scoring='neg_mean_squared_error',
                            cv = len(X_test), n_jobs = -1)
    
    print(f'Degree-{i} polynomial, MSE: {abs(scores_poly).mean()}')
```

Gives :

```
Degree-1 polynomial, MSE: 22.2130277556231
Degree-2 polynomial, MSE: 17.01069056186582
Degree-3 polynomial, MSE: 17.283994438261868
Degree-4 polynomial, MSE: 17.401530563158406
Degree-5 polynomial, MSE: 15.934755858114803
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So from what I get, there's no way I can train the `model` with `X_train, y_train` and then calculate the `MSE` of the `model` using `X_test, y_test` and `cross_val_score`? Because from your answer I understand that the `model` is being 'trained' using directly `X_test, y_test`, right? For the sake of not misusing functions I should: keep training `model` with `X_train, y_train`, then using `y_pred = model.predict(X_test)` and then get `MSE` using, from `sklearn.metrics`, the `mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred)`..

Comment: Which leads to the question... how do I proceed to calculate `mean_squared_error` using the `LeaveOneOut` cross-validation method? (Considering I want to train my model with `X_train` and then do the cross-validation and calculate `MSE` of `X_test`.

Comment: Yes, you would do `mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred)`

Comment: `LeaveOneOut` only applies for training the data. I don't understand how you use `LeaveOneOut` for scoring your test data. what is there to leave out?